# Not able to execute system procedure on SQL Server at AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We currently have a Amazon RDS instance running SQL Server, and we're having a issue which we hope you guys can help.

We're trying to execute the query:

```
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
```

But it's returned:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure sp_OACreate, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OACreate', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

After some research apparently the problem is that the SQL Server user executing it needs to have permission to some resources at the "master" database, which far as we've seen even the "sa" user on AWS RDS don't have.

Besides this procedure there are other system procedures we need to be able to execute.

Do you guys know if it's possible to give an user the permission to execute this on AWS RDS? And if so, how to?

Thanks in advance!

Edit #1: 
Already tried to execute:

```
USE master;
GRANT EXEC ON sp_OACreate TO myuser;
GRANT EXEC ON sp_OAMethod TO myuser;
GRANT EXEC ON sp_OAGetProperty TO myuser;
GRANT EXEC ON sp_OADestroy TO myuser;
GRANT EXEC ON sp_OAGetErrorInfo TO myuser;
```

Which returns:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Cannot find the user 'myuser', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

PS: the "myuser" user exists. Those commands were executed with the "sa" user.

Comment: From [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oacreate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions): *"Requires membership in the **sysadmin** fixed server role or execute permission directly on this Stored Procedure. `Ole Automation Procedures` configuration must be **enabled** to use any system procedure related to OLE Automation."* If the login shouldn't have `sysadmin` rights, give its linked `USER` execute permissions on the object

Comment: @Larnu: question was edited with what I already tried ("Edit #1"). Please, check if this is what you meant.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you were allowed to run this procedure on any hosted SQL Server solution, as it basically allows you to run arbitrary code on a server managed by the hoster.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. Apparently is exactly this. I included a answer below from AWS Developer Forums saying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to AWS Developer Forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=876085

> Sorry, OLE Automation isn’t supported in RDS. If you absolutely must use those stored procedures then you’ll have to run a self-managed SQL Server on EC2.